# How to get SHA1 code in new version of android studio 4.2?

Tags: java, android, sha1, android-studio-4.2

Before this update we can get SHA1 code from Gradle but now it's look like it's changed.

[image]

Comment: Yes it seems somethings off with Android 4.2 here

Comment: I tried this in 4.2 getting same error so I downgraded to 4.1.2 at sha1 in working just fine

Comment: follow these steps [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76617495/12748481)

Answer (score 81):

Fixed this by doing this:
[Check here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPxHp.png)

1. File
2. Settings
3. Experimental
4. Unchecked the 'Do not build gradle task list during gradle sync' and click 'OK'
5. Go to file
6. Sync project with Gradle files
7. You will see the option on Signing reports under:
   Gradle -> Tasks ->Android -> Signing Report.

8.Check the image below
[image: Here]

Comment: Signing Report Runs but does not show any logs.

Comment: It shows the report user run  tab on the android studio tray menus. As shown above, Scroll down, you will see MD5,SHA1,SHA-256 etc.

Answer (score 42):

#### **Option 1 :**

**1. Open **`Gradle`** window from the right side and click on **`Execute Gradle task`** icon.**

[image]

**2. Add **`signingreport`** beside the "`gradle`" and press Enter.**
[image]

#### **Option 2 :**

- Open **`Terminal`** in android studio, type **`./gradlew signingReport`** and press Enter.

[image]

Comment: Option 1 work for me

Comment: Good one and working!

Comment: this Solved also for me... 

Answer (score 20):

Try using this command line in AndroidStudio Terminal

./gradlew signingReport

Comment: Recommended. One of the easiest way

Answer (score 14):

Step 1: Click Execute Gradle task

[image]

Step 2: Type : "signingreport"  and Enter

Answer (score 4):

4.2 do not build gradle task by default.
you kan open it in file > settings > experimental, uncheck "do not build gradle task list during gradle sync", then sync project with gradle files

Comment: Signing Report Runs but does not show any logs.

Comment: Confirmed here, 100% working

Answer (score 4):

Click on Double Shift on android studio

Enter **"Run anything"**

Now enter **"gradlew signingReport"**

Enter

Comment: works like charm !!!

Answer (score 3):

In Android Studio, go to Build **menu -> Generate Signed Bundle / APK**

Select your **keystore and key alias**.

Copy the key store path and the key alias.

Here, the path is `/Users/technofreek/Documents/testkeystore`

and the alias is **key0**.

[image]

Open terminal and type the command

```
keytool -list -v -keystore <your keystore path> -alias <your alias>
```

For this example, here’s the command

```
keytool -list -v -keystore /Users/technofreek/Documents/testkeystore -alias key0
```

This will print your **SHA1**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. Open your project in Android Studio
2. Click on `Gradle` tab on the right
   [image]
3. Click on the elephant `Execute gradle task`
   [image]
4. In the popup that appears, type `signingreport`
   [image]
5. Wait and check the run tab. You will see the SHA1

Answer (score 1):

4.2 do not build gradle task by default.
you kan open it in file > settings > experimental, uncheck "do not build gradle task list during gradle sync", then sync project with gradle files

yes its 100% working

Comment: Signing Report Runs but does not show any logs.

Answer (score 1):

1. Double shift
2. You add 'gradle'
3. You look for the option 'Sync Project with Gradle Files'
4. Click on that option
5. Enter the gradle section again and it will be generated

**Greetings! :]**

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1):

In my case instead of "./gradlew signingReport", "gradlew signingReport" solved my issue

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

[image: here]

Double click it and you'll get your MD5, SHA, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible gotcha: make sure your Run output is visible. You may have to expand the Run output screen from right to left, like so:

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XF2Qc.png)    
[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ctqn.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on the gradle. Top right on the Android Studio. ...
2. Now click on icon as seen in below picture. A new searchable windows/screen will open.

[image]

3. Now type,gradle signingreport and press Enter to start generating SHA KEY as seen in below picture.
4. Your SHA Key will generate as seen in this picture.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

please goto **Tools** > **firebase**, the Assistant tab on your right will open and then choose what feature you want, either **authentication**, **realTimeDatabase** etc the click **connect to firebase** and **firbase console** will open from where you get to select your project from the list of projects and then it will connect automatically, everything is donw for you, i hope this helps

Thanks